# Read csv in javascript using d3 and assign to variable

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have some data in a csv that I would like to read in using d3 (version 4) and *assign to a global variable*.  All of the examples I can find online ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285441/how-to-read-in-csv-with-d3) and [here](http://learnjsdata.com/read_data.html)) read in a csv and then print the results to the console.

So if I run:

```
d3.csv("mydata.csv", function(data) {
  console.log(data[0]);
});
```

Or

```
d3.csv("mydata.csv", function(d) {
  return {
    country : d.country,
    month : d.month,
    count : +d.count
  };
}, function(data) {
  console.log(data[0]);
});
```

I get the first line of my csv file.

However, if I try to run a similar script and write the results to a variable, ie:

```
var mydata = d3.csv("mydata.csv");
```

Or

```
var mydata = d3.csv("mydata.csv", function(d) {
  return {
    country : d.country,
    month : d.month,
    count : +d.count
  };
}, function(data) {
  console.log(data[0]);
});
```

And try to examine the variable `mydata` in the console, I am given a list of methods, not the actual data. Ie,

[image]

What am I doing wrong?  How to I assign the data in the csv to a global variable, so I can eventually use it for visualization?  I think I am interested in a synchronous solution, so I am open to not using d3.csv() if there are other functions out there that will simply read in the data and assign it to a global variable.

Comment: `d3.csv` returns an object related to the request, and that's what you're seeing in the image you shared. Answering your question: you are already assigning the data array to a variable in your first snippet, called `data`.

Comment: Sure, I am assigning my data to a variable called `data`, but only within the function that prints to console.  Maybe more specifically, how to I assign my data to a global variable?

Comment: @AmadouKone assigning to a global doesn't work because reading csv is asynchronous. You need to access it in a callback or use a promise.

Comment: I am planning on making visualizations with the data in the csv.  So should I make all of those visualizations within a callback function?  The tutorial I am following just reads in the CSV to an object and uses that object.