# D3 bubble chart - get data from json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm a beginner when it comes to javascript and D3. I want to create a bubble chart using D3 and I need to get the data from an external file. I've searched for other ways but it looks like nothing works. Does anyone know how can I do it?

```
function animatedBubbleChart() {
    var bubbleChart = new d3.svg.BubbleChart({
        supportResponsive: true,
        size: 800,
        innerRadius: 600 / 3.5,
        radiusMin: 50,
        data: {
          items: [//replace this with data from a json
            {text: "2010", count: "170"},
            {text: "2011", count: "170"},
            {text: "2012", count: "170"},
            {text: "2013", count: "170"},
            {text: "2014", count: "170"},
            {text: "2015", count: "170"},
            {text: "2016", count: "170"},
          ],
          eval: function (item) {return item.count;},
          classed: function (item) {return item.text.split(" ").join("");}
        },
        plugins: [
          {
```

Comment: Well, this doesn't seem like a pure D3 code, there is some kind of plugin here. So, please edit your question showing us what's the plugin you're using, so you can get proper help. Also, I removed the snippet, it is for running code only.

Comment: What doesn't work? Is loading data the only issue? Please update your question to elaborate.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the d3.csv function [Documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#csv) Returns a new request for the CSV file at the specified url. This question has a good answer! [LINK TO QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285441/how-to-read-in-csv-with-d3)
example

```
d3.csv("test.csv", function (data) {    
    console.log(data[0]);
}
```

for json similarly

```
d3.json("test.json", function(data) {
  console.log(data[0]);
});
```

I would try and set up a fiddle so that people can better help you!

Comment: not sure why I got a downvote, this is the correct answer, if asker could put up a fiddle Id append his work to reflect that..

Comment: I think he was asking how you could make an Ajax request then get parse the data in d3 chart. Same thing I am looking for