# Uncaught TypeError: d3.queue is not a function D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, chord-diagram

I'm trying to create a Chord Diagram using D3.js to show the relationship between different clients and suppliers, but
I keep getting the following error when running the page, and here's my code:

> Uncaught TypeError: d3.queue is not a function
>       at chord.html:47

```
      d3.queue()
        .defer(d3.json, 'NewData/Client_Supplier-matrix.json')
        .defer(d3.csv, 'NewData/Client_Supplier.csv')
        .await(function(err, matrix, mmap) { 
          if (err) console.log(err);
          _.each(mmap, function (d, i) { d.id=i; d.data=d.color })
          drawChords(matrix, mmap);
        });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you are attempting to use D3 v5 to run code designed for D3 v4.   According to the [D3 5.0 release notes](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md):

> D3 5.0 also deprecates and removes the d3-queue module. Use Promise.all to run a batch of asynchronous tasks in parallel, or a helper library such as p-queue to control concurrency.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534470/d3-js-v5-promise-all-replaced-d3-queue) for an example of how to convert `d3.queue` to `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 1):

try this command 
`npm install d3-queue`